# Compute a mean of an array group by unique values in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, group-by

If I have an array

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2]
```

How can I compute the mean by each unique value in the array using `numpy.mean()`.

I'd like to have `[6/12, 2/12,4/12]` not using count or len but only `np.mean`

I am just starting with Python.

Comment: What do you mean you can’t use len() or count()? These are the best and only options! I’m not sure what you want when you say you can “only” use the np.mean function. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I compute the mean by each unique value in the array using `numpy.mean()`.

Using `numpy.mean` might not possible.

But to achieve that you can use `numpy.bincount` and `len`

```
import numpy as np

np.bincount(a)/len(a)
array([0.5       , 0.16666667, 0.33333333])
```

Answer (score 1):

You make no sense when you say you can only use the `np.mean` function. You need something else, unless you want to implement these functions yourself, which makes no sense.

In fact, you don’t even really need `np.mean` at all, but instead, `np.unique`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])
unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts = True)
s = sum(counts)
means = [count / s for count, value in zip(counts, unique)]
```

**EDIT**:

Of course, you could just simplify this to:

```
np.unique(a, return_counts = True)[1]  / a.size
```

which was pointed out by another answerer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Counter for counting unique values count as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])
output = np.array(list(Counter(a).values()))/a.size
```

output will be:

```
output : [0.5        0.33333333 0.16666667]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the mean of counts (and not the values themselves), you can use `np.unique` to get the counts. `a` is your array:

```
np.unique(a,return_counts=True)[1]/a.size
```

output:

```
[0.5        0.16666667 0.33333333]
```